Python linter and code formatter recommendations
I am looking for Python linter and code formatter recommendations.
Requirements:

Works on the command line and as a part of a pre-commit hook.
Works as a part of an editor/IDE (specifically, Emacs and VS Code).
Is compatible with GitHub Actions.


There is a nice resource here: Tools for format and error checking in your programming language - Code Review Meta Stack Exchange: Python, which is an answer to a related question (thank you, Peilonrayz!).

I was also curious about ruff. If anyone has experience with it, your answer/comment would be appreciated!

Ruff is a modern Python linter and formatter.
Its main highlight is the speed, which claims to be up to 100x faster than the other alternatives.
Ruff ships with a built-in language server, that enables it to be used in any editor that supports the LSP (Neovim, Emcas, Sublime, etc).
There is also a dedicated VS Code extension.
Also it has a pre-commit hook from the authors: https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff-pre-commit

Any comments on GitHub Actions with Ruff, for example Integrations | Ruff?

I haven't used it specifically with GitHub Actions. I did use it within Jenkins pipelines, since it provides a CLI tool to lint and format, the process to integrate it, is straightforward.

I use black & isort for code formatting and flake8 for style checking and linting. Pylint is a great addition too, it's stricter and provides detailed feedback - great for improved code quality over time.

All of them are supposed to work on CLI - that's their purpose, no such tools use GUIs. All of the popular ones also have a pre-commit hook, e.g.:

Ruff in separate repo
Black in its official repo
flake8 in its official repo
pylint in its official repo

etc. The list of available hooks is vast, especially for Python, as the tool is written in Python.
Most of them are available for editors as well. E.g. for VSCode:

Ruff made by the author
Black official from MS
flake8 official from MS
pylint official from MS

Everything is compatible with GitHub Actions, so that point is not really a thing to consider. Some formatters just have ready solutions, others can be simply installed on some ready Python environment, the configuration just takes few minutes longer.

What you should instead be looking at is: optimization, capabilities and development progression.
Ruff is by far the best and most modern option, but note that a lot of options from other linters are still missing, although it also provides some unique ones and is a linter and formatter in one. It has good configurability, which e.g. Black is missing. It's by far the fastest one because it uses Rust, which helps in bigger or more frequently updated projects. It's also updated pretty much weekly while the others can be much slower.

Given the rapid update schedule of Ruff, what method do you use to keep the local Ruff version updated and in sync on all the developers' machines in a team of developers?

I mean, just any sort of good package manager will do. I'm a fan of PDM, rye also has been gaining popularity recently.
